# responsive layout on React application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

the task is to show different components based on the device width;

I've come up with two variants:

1. write a React Component which will take several components, on each width (sm, md, xl). It'll automatically check the device width and render only one component based on the width. ([example](https://goshakkk.name/different-mobile-desktop-tablet-layouts-react/))

```html
<DeviceChecker>
    <Desktop>
        <List/>
    </Desktop>
    <Mobile>
        <Carousel/>
    </Mobile>
</DeviceChecker>
```

What I don't like in this approach is checking the width on window resize event.

2. Write both components in React but using CSS media queries show or hide each, like this:

```html
<div>
    <Carousel className="sm" />
    <List className="md" />
</div>
```

what I don't like in this case is that React will actually render both components but one of them will be simple hidden

I know how to implement both variants, but the question is **Which one is correct way to write Responsive Layouts for React Applications?**

Comment: check https://github.com/contra/react-responsive

Answer (score 0):

```css
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  section.dashboard .slick-list .slick-track {
    display: flex;
  }
  section.dashboard .slick-list .slide {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  header .wrapper .article h1 span.arrow {
    display:none;
  }

  header .wrapper .article .description {
    max-height: 300px
  }
} 

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

  .container header .wrapper {
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:5%;
    width:480px;
  }

  .container header .header-nav-area #nav_container  {
    display:flex;
  }

  .container header form {
    display:block;
  }

  .container header .menu-icon {
    display:none;
  }

  header .wrapper .article footer {
    display: block;
  }

  section.dashboard .slick-list .slick-track {
    display: flex;
    min-width: 309px;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  section.dashboard .slick-list .slick-track[index="2"] {
    display: flex;
  }

  section.dashboard .slick-list .slide {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

For more detail visit;
https://itnext.io/3-ways-to-implement-responsive-design-in-your-react-app-bcb6ee7eb424